# Need an application to fix a XML with unescaped chars

Tags: java, php, xml, escaping, rdf

This [XML](http://www.mediafire.com/?dpjgb7n35t9ymvp) *(rdf file extension, but is XML)* was generated by a automatic tool, but unfortunately have various "unescaped" strings like

```
<tag xml:lang="fr">L'insuline (du latin insula, île) </tag>
```

And the parser (and reasoner software) crash with this...

**Java** or **PHP** solutions are valid to me too!

Thanks,
Celso

Comment: That's not XML. It only happens to resemble it. Your automatic tool should produce valid XML. Fix it.

Comment: Add tag for the language you'd prefer the answer in.

Comment: Its XML, because RDF is a XML !!! google first and comment after

Comment: Which character are you referring to?  The circumflex "i" or the single quote?  Also, you did not include the error message.  Please edit your post and provide more information.

Comment: RDF is not XML, RDF is an abstract data model, RDF/XML is just one of many serializations of that model

Comment: I found the real solution: replace all xsd String by rdf Plain Literal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general method that I use a lot to make sure a String is escaped properly for XML.

```
private static final String AMP = "&amp;";
private static final String LT = "&lt;";
private static final String GT = "&gt;";
private static final String QUOTE = "&quot;";
private static final String APOS = "&apos;";

public static String encodeEntities(String dirtyString) {

    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    char[] chars = dirtyString.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] > 0x7f) {
            buff.append("&#" + (int) chars[i] + ";");
            continue;
        }

        switch (chars[i]) {
        case '&':
            buff.append(AMP);
            break;
        case '<':
            buff.append(LT);
            break;
        case '\'':
            buff.append(APOS);
            break;
        case '"':
            buff.append(QUOTE);
            break;
        case '>':
            buff.append(GT);
            break;
        default:
            buff.append(chars[i]);
            break;
        }
    }

    return buff.toString();
}
```

Comment: It's much better to use a library that does this for you. Typically these days I use the XMLStreamWriter API, with the Saxon serializer behind it.

Answer (score 1):

The xml given by the OP is well-formed xml as the single quote character is valid and so is the circumflex "i", neither needs escaping. I would make sure you're using a text encoding such as UTF-8. Here's quick java example that does an identity transformation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    StreamResult s = new StreamResult(System.out);
    t.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader("<tag xml:lang=\"fr\">L'insuline (du latin insula, île) </tag>")), s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML fragment given by the OP looks well-formed. Neither the apostrophe nor the i-circumflex needs escaping. The most likely problem is that the XML is encoded using iso-8859-1, but lacks an XML declaration, so the parser think it is in UTF-8 encoding. The solution then is to add the XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`, which tells the parser how to decode the characters. (For a document containing only ASCII characters, iso-8859-1 and utf-8 are indistinguishable, so this problem only surfaces when you use characters outside the ASCII range).

A word of advice: if you had given the error message generated by the parser, you wouldn't have got so many incorrect answers.